# my program doesn't execute code in the if statement

Tags: java, file

Im creating a program that can create a directory and then place a file inside said directory. As you can see, after the person specifies the directory, the program is supposed to check if either the directory exists or doesn't exist and create a directory if it doesn't exist or say that there is already a directory with that name. Whenever I run the program, and i put a directory that already exists, instead of saying that the said directory already exist it skips straight to the fail message and proceeds with making the new file in the existing directory. How can I fix the code so that it gives the proper "file existing" message and THEN proceed with the code, instead of it just saying the fail message?

```
Please enter where you want your file...
/Users/FyuZheN/Desktop/test
[Console] Directory does not exist! Creating one...
[Console] Fail! Couldn't create directory!
[Console] What would you like to call your new file?
test.jar
[Console] Created new file test.jar
Successfully created new file: /Users/FyuZheN/Desktop/test/test.jar
```

Also, if the directory the user specified is a directory that cannot exist. This happens...

```
Please enter where you want your file...
awdawdawd
[Console] Directory does not exist! Creating one...
[Console] Success! Created directory awdawdawd
[Console] What would you like to call your new file?
dawdawd
[Console] Created new file dawdawd
Successfully created new file: awdawdawd/dawdawd
```

How can I re-code it so that it gives the proper error message and asks the user again for a valid Directory?

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class findFile {

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean success = false;

    System.out.println("Please enter where you want your file...");
    String usrdir = s.nextLine();

    File directory = new File(usrdir);

    if (directory.exists() && directory.isFile()) {

        System.out.println("[Console] This directory already exists");

    } else {

        System.out.println("[Console] Directory does not exist! Creating one...");
        success = directory.mkdir();

        if (success) {

            System.out.println("[Console] Success! Created directory " + usrdir);

        } else {

            System.out.println("[Console] Fail! Couldn't create directory!");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("[Console] What would you like to call your new file?");
    String filename = s.next(filename = ".txt");

    File f = new File(directory, filename);

    if(f.exists() && f.isFile()) {

        System.out.println("[Console] File already exists!");

    } else {

        System.out.println("[Console] Created new file " + filename);
        success = f.createNewFile();

        if (success) {

            System.out.printf("Successfully created new file: %s%n", f);

        } else {

            System.out.printf("Failed to create new file: %s%n", f);
        }
    }

    s.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Add a while loop and a boolean folderexists + if(folderexists){add new file}.

Comment: `isFile()` is always false for a directory.  Perhaps you meant to call [isDirectory()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory--)?

Comment: Both directory.exists() and directory.isFile() must return true. Being as it's never entering that area it means one or both aren't returning true. Perhaps what VGR or maybe your `&&` should be an `||`? I'm not familiar of the use of words file here as it would seem if the directory included a file you would skip ahead and not ask for file?

Comment: It would only enter that section if the pathname you provide is both a pathname with a file at the end such as c://somedirectory/somefile.exe

Answer (score 0):

To make your code ask again, do sth like:

```
while(true){
 //ask for new foldername
 if(usrdir.equals("exit")){
   break;//the user should be able to.leave your program
 }
 //rest of your code
}
```

To create a new file, you need a folder, so do:

```
boolean folderexists=false;
//if folder creation worked or if folder exists set to true
if(folderexists){
//ask for filename etc
}
```

Comment: im not exactly sure where you're coming from. do you mind elaborating more on your answer?